# Visual Studio 2015 installer crashes before it starts

Tags: windows-10, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015, but I keep getting an error:

> Setup detected an issue during the operation.

Here is the log that gets generated from the installer program:

dd_vs_community_20161011154142.log -- [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SptGtwZL)

I think that this might be the important part:

```
[123C:2F78][2016-10-11T15:41:44]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Windows.Media.Typeface..ctor(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)
   at MS.Internal.Text.DynamicPropertyReader.GetTypeface(DependencyObject element)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target, Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowImpl()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunInteractiveUI(ViewModelCommonUi viewModel)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[123C:2F78][2016-10-11T15:41:44]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: InnerException: Info:
[123C:2F78][2016-10-11T15:41:44]e000: MUX:  ERROR: More data is available.

[123C:2F78][2016-10-11T15:41:44]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValueNames()
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSourceCollection.SetFontSources()
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FontSourceCollection.GetEnumerator()
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.BuildFamilyList(List`1& familyList, SortedDictionary`2& familyNameList, SortedList`2& frequentStrings)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.FamilyCollection.MS.Internal.FontCache.IFontCacheElement.AddToCache(CheckedPointer newPointer, ElementCacher cacher)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.HashTable.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e, Boolean add)
   at MS.Internal.FontCache.CacheManager.Lookup(IFontCacheElement e)
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily.PreCreateDefaultFamilyCollection()
   at System.Windows.Media.FontFamily..cctor()
```

ISO Sha-1 matches the sha listed [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sha-vs)

```
Sha-1: C838DF0D2DAD6E763DF5A7974F5FFCD45B98FD0E
```

I have tried all the methods I have seen on google but nothing seems to be working. What is it that is causing me to not be able to install Visual Studio?

Comment: Try updating your Windows installation to the current build revision from the log file it appears your running *.33 which isn't the current version

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do what exactly?  What's the last cumulative patch you installed and what build of Windows are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your log, it's having trouble dealing with your fonts.  Perhaps you have one or more corrupted/incompatible fonts installed.

A quick Google for `e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Windows.Media.Typeface` returns this Microsoft KB article:

- [Visual Studio setup crashes with an exception after the splash screen is shown](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2978135)

...which seems to agree with my original assessment:

> This issue may occur because there are issues with certain fonts on your system, such as invalid characters in the font path or invalid file timestamps.

You can read that article for suggestions on identifying and correcting fonts that don't agree with the VS installer.

Comment: I am going to guess that maybe this file... `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\EQUATION\MTEXTRA.TTF`

Comment: Modifying some of the font names in the registry seemed to work...

Answer (score -1):

For posterity: if you are using Adobe software, it's installing a font handler that allows using Mac-style TTC files (TrueType font collections). These fonts install into the system fine, and are generally supported in ordinary apps, however WPF apps seem to crash because of them present in the system. Check your 
list of fonts under:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts

for any fonts with the *.ttc extension. Copy them to a temporary directory, remove them from the system Fonts directory using Windows Explorer (standard way), extract individual ttf fonts from the ttc collections using an online converter of your choice and install them back. WPF applications stop crashing and you get to keep your fonts.